# Android tutorial "Cannot resolve symbol 'setText' "

Tags: android

I am trying to work through the tutorial found here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

I am getting the above error when trying to build the app. I have looked round and round trying to find an answer, and also tried fault checking my own code but to no avail.

Below is my code:

```
    package com.example.chris.helloworld;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
}

Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(message);
}
```

And the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.chris.helloworld.DisplayMessageActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Apologies for the poor question, I now realise the obvious error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place these lines:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(message);
```

**Inside** onCreate (or some other method). You can't place code like that outside methods in Java. I say `onCreate` because you load views. That should be called from onCreate some or another way, but an external method called from onCreate would also do

So your code would be:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);
}
```

And this applies to everything. The more or less only thing you can do outside methods is declare variables. Setting those variables, changing them (through methods like `setText` in the case of textview) has to be done inside a method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very informative, even though I should have spotted this myself!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

   TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
   textView.setText(message);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you have this inside the method onCreate?

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(message);
```

You have to put this in onCreate or other method.